# How to estimate memory usage for Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

We are using Prometheus for scraping metrics and keep them for 8 hours (for longer peried we are using Victoria Metrics). I tried to find out, how much MEM should Prometheus have for current amount of series. I find out [How much RAM does Prometheus 2.x need for cardinality and ingestion?](https://www.robustperception.io/how-much-ram-does-prometheus-2-x-need-for-cardinality-and-ingestion) with calculator. From the article, there is some points which are unclear to me:

- **Number of Time Series*** - it should be result of `max_over_time(prometheus_tsdb_head_series[1d])` query. In my case, there is multiple results, so I sum it with `sum(max_over_time(prometheus_tsdb_head_series[1d]))`. Is this approach right?
- **Average Labels Per Time Series*** - count number of key-value pairs of all labels and count average. E.g. `{a="123", b="456"}` is counted as 2.
- **Number of Unique Label Pairs*** - find uniq key-value pairs. E.g. `{a="123", b="456"}` and `{a="123", b="abc"}` equals to 2 uniq label pairs
- **Average Bytes per Label Pair* (Including the =, "" and ,)** - e.g. `{ "__name__": "up", "app_version": "0509b54", "instance": "1", "job": "event-metric-exporterd", "stack_version": "MR" }`. I remove spaces and `{`, `}`. So final string is `"__name__":"up","app_version":"0509b54","instance":"1","job":"event-metric-exporterd","stack_version":"MR"`. Then, I encode it with `utf-8` and get length of string, in this case 106. I do this process for each uniq labels and count average. Is this right?
- **Bytes per Sample** - there is query `rate(prometheus_tsdb_compaction_chunk_size_bytes_sum[1d])/rate(prometheus_tsdb_compaction_chunk_samples_sum[1d])` which again, in my case return multiple series. It take `max()` because it is worst case scenario.

The calculator counts:

- **Cardinality Memory** - how much memory Prometheus needs for various series/cardinality? Do I understand correctly?
- **Ingestion Memory** - memory used by Prometheus to ingest data - load and process it from targets?

Do I understand correctly **Cardinality Memory** and **Ingestion Memory**? Is my calculation process correct? Is there better way how to estimate memory for Prometheus?

Using Prometheus in docker `prometheus:v2.29.1`.

Comment: You ever get an answer to this? It seems not, but maybe you figured something out and just didn't update this question?

Comment: Hi, I did not. I implemented it as above, but in the end, it does not work at all. Sometimes the estimation show me I should add more memory, sometimes it shows 4G of MEM is enough but prometheus has 8 but MEM usage is on 90 percent.